# Graphics for Simple 2D JS Game

Tags: javascript, html, dom, canvas, svg

I want to make a Angry Birds kind of game in JavaScript.
Flat 2D soft egde game with no abstract user input or no complex animations.

The idea with this game is to learn to make games in JS, so i can make my own non rip-off game.

The question is wich graphics should I use for most efficiency?

- DOM
- SVG
- Canvas
- Ect.

I know games should be made in JS because of inefficiency, but thats is'nt my question - my question is what is the most efficient way in JS.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use Canvas / WebGL with a library or framework to help.  There is PhaserJS https://phaser.io for making games - this is built on PixiJS http://www.pixijs.com for more general interactive works.  There is ZIM http://zimjs.com which adds many conveniences, components and controls and sits on top of CreateJS at http://createjs.com. These types of frameworks are how most people are making games on the Canvas.

Answer (score -1):

You should use canvas. It gives better performance than the rest.

Comment: But SVG is responsive.

Comment: thanks, is canvas good at responsive design for multiple devices? :)

Comment: yes you can use some css to make it adjustable in any screen size